# How to combine a object to an mixamo character animation in blender

Tags: animation, mesh

I created an animation in blender using mixamo character. The animation consists of three animations combined. Walk, Run and Jump. After completing the mixamo animation I realized I forgot to add a backpack to the mixamo character, but when I add the backpack and click animation the backpack doesn't stay on the character. Is there a way to join the backpack to the mixamo character without messing up anything. I am using Blender 3.01. Below is the image. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. move your backpack where it should be

(sorry for taking this simple box - i am lazy)

[image]

2. select your box
3. shift select your armature

[image]

4. go to pose mode
5. now select the bone which should be the parent of your backpack - now this depends how you want it to look...but i chose this one here:

[image]

6. press CTRL-P -> Bone

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It worked. I saved so much time thanks to you. Bless you. :) @Chris

Comment: you are welcome